# Why Logging is not working on django website?

Tags: python, django

This is what i tried . 
In my view.py file ,

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("mylog")
logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.INFO,datefmt='%d/%m/%y %I:%M:%S')
```

Then inside a function ,

```
logger.debug("this is an error")
logger.warning("This is a warning")
print "This is a test line '
```

I have not touched the settings.py file .its pretty much the same.

```
LOGGING = {

    'version': 1,

    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'handlers': {

        'mail_admins': {

            'level': 'ERROR',

            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'

        }

    },

    'loggers': {

        'django.request': {

            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],

            'level': 'ERROR',

            'propagate': True,

        },

    }
```

When i run the server , and call the function , nothing happens . no error , nothing .

I just want to see a log line on the console .

Comment: Your config has 'level': 'ERROR', and you're calling logging.warning() and logging.debug() ... so it's not supposed to do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this to handlers:

```
'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
           }
```

and in loggers:

```
    'django': {
        'handlers':['console'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'INFO',
    },
```

The log level could be the same or different - In fact the handler defines the minimum level it will log, while the logger defines the minimum level it will send to handler. If one handler is used by two or more loggers - it should ideally has the lowest level from both loggers.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @jpic for pointing the loggers section.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need a logger that uses this handler ?

Comment: @jpic: Thanks for reminding on the logger, I've edited the text.

Comment: Thanks all of you . The info was very useful . However I found the bug which because of none of these factors . I had another setting file local_setting.py in my 'conf' folder . There was another log config declared . I commented out those line and to my surprise , everything started working (with all the settings and code in view file unchanged). I think some kind of conflict due to multiple declaration of log configs