# django logging configuration not working as it should

Tags: python, django, logging

I have project with (Django=1.9.7) and celery, the project structure is as such

```
myproject
-- manage.py
-- myproject
   -- config
      -- config.py
      -- logging_config.py
      -- celery_config.py
   -- settings.py
-- app_1
   -- models.py
   -- tasks.py
   -- views.py
 -- app_N
   -- models.py
   -- tasks.py
   -- views.py
```

Here is my [logging_config.py](http://dpaste.com/19T6WC2)

```

```
import os

from .config import LOG_FILE, REQUEST_LOG_FILE, LOGGING_LEVEL


# print LOG_FILE, REQUEST_LOG_FILE
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'django': {
            'format': 'django %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s/process_id=%(process)d/(%(thread)d)] %(name)s : %(message)s'
        },
        'general': {
            'format': 'general %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s/process_id=%(process)d/(%(thread)d)] %(name)s : %(message)s'
        },
        'celery': {
            'format': 'celery %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s/process_id=%(process)d/(%(thread)d)] %(name)s : %(message)s'
        },
        'request': {
            'format': 'request %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s/process_id=%(process)d/(%(thread)d)] %(name)s : %(message)s'
        },
        'console': {
            'format': 'console %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s/process_id=%(process)d/(%(thread)d)] %(name)s : %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'django': {
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '{file}'.format(file=LOG_FILE),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'django',
        },
        'general': {
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '{file}'.format(file=LOG_FILE),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'general',
        },
        'requests': {
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '{file}'.format(file=REQUEST_LOG_FILE),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'request',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': False,
        },
        'celery.tasks': {
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '{file}'.format(file=LOG_FILE),
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'celery',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
            # 'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'general'],
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'requests'],
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'celery.tasks': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins','celery.tasks'],
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'django'],
            'level': LOGGING_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True
        },

    }
}
```

```

**Note :** 
LOGGING_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'

The logging config work perfectly in local server.. all the logs gets set to the respective file,

but on PROD it fails.. only `django` logger works but rest of the loggers don't print to the respective file

Can anyone help.. as I am not able to pin point what i am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
 A Point to note is I am getting the error messages correctly via mail, what i am not getting is the debug or info messages in the respective files. except for all the logs in the django logger, all the logs for celerytask, any app are missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Logging is not working on django website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975798/why-logging-is-not-working-on-django-website)

Comment: Add your logging config into the question **itself**, not from a pastebin

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: logging_config file in the question itself.